# SQLite database not found on physical device, works on emulator

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am developing an Android app that uses an SQLite database to store data. The app works fine on the emulator, but when I test it on a physical device(XAIOME NOTE 8), the first table that is read at runtime is not being found.

I have checked the app permissions and granted them all, and the database file is being saved to the app folder on the device. I am using the following code to copy the database from the assets folder to the app folder:

```
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(AppDataBase.db_NAME);
            String outfile = context.getDatabasePath(AppDataBase.db_NAME).getPath();
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
            byte[] buft = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buft)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buft, 0, length);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
```

I have also checked the database file name and table names and they are correct. I have tried searching for solutions online but have not found any that work.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**Part of the code that is giving an error:**

```
    @SuppressLint("Range")
    public List<Articles_of_Article_Screen> getAllArtigos(){

        openDataBase();

        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM artigos ORDER by id";
        List<Articles_of_Article_Screen> list = new ArrayList<>();

        cursor = db.rawQuery(SQL,null);

        Articles_of_Article_Screen obj;

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

            do{
                obj = new Articles_of_Article_Screen(
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("titulo")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("previa")));

                list.add(obj);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }

        closeDataBase();

        return list;

    }
```

[image]

Comment: What is in `openDataBase()`? Are you sure your code is connecting to the database? Have you tried stepping through the code and breaking on a point where you have access to `db` and executing a pragma like `db.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_list")`? I can't recall the exact syntax but a google search will show you) If I recall with SQLite it it doesn't find a DB at the url provided it will create an empty one.

Comment: The openDataBase opens the database that is in the folder databases
     private void openDataBase() {
         String dbPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(db_NAME).getPath();
         db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
     }
     private void closeDataBase(){
         if (db != null) {
             db.close();
             db = null;
         }
     }